# if $\frac{f''}{f}=\lambda$ is constant and $f$ is periodic, then $0\le\lambda$.

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, fourier-analysis

> if $\frac{f''}{f}=\lambda$ is constant and $f$ is periodic with period $L\in \mathbb R$, then
> $\lambda\le0$, where $f$ is a twice differentiable function on
> $\mathbb R$.

I recognise $\frac{f''}{f}=\lambda$ is the standing-wave equation $f''-\lambda f=0$ also its general solution is $A\cos cx+B\cos cx$(even for complex $x$), where $c^2=-\lambda$. So, if $-\lambda\le0$, $c=+,-\sqrt{|\lambda|i}$, and $A\cos cx$, $B\cos cx$ will not be periodic with real value period. But I am stuck at showing $A\cos cx+B\cos cx$ is also not periodic.

The above is my attempt, which involves the solution of standing-wave equation. But the statemnt is "simple", I am wondering if there is any direct way to prove it in the sense of not involving the general solution of standing-wave.

Comment: I think there is a typo. It should be $\lambda \leq 0$ instead of $\lambda \geq 0$.

Comment: Think of the general solution being ...

$$f(x) = Ae^{cx} + Be^{-cx}$$
with
$$c=\sqrt \lambda$$
Do you see that the solution is periodic if and only if $c$ has no real part?

Comment: Is $f$ assumed to be real-valued or complex-valued? Is $\lambda$ real or complex?

Answer (score 1):

In fact the general solution is based on $e^{\sqrt{\lambda}x}$.

(Edit: more precisely writing, $y_{general}=c_1e^{\sqrt{\lambda}x} + c_2e^{-\sqrt{\lambda}x}$ , where $c_1 , c_2$ are constants)

When $\lambda < 0$ , following your notation if we take $c^2 = -\lambda$ then we have:
$$e^{\sqrt{\lambda}x} = e^{icx} = \cos{cx} + i\sin{cx}$$
$$e^{-\sqrt{\lambda}x} = e^{-icx} = \cos{cx} - i\sin{cx}$$
which are periodic functions.

Now, your question states that the function is periodic. Note that this would not be possible if $\lambda > 0$ , because $e^{\sqrt{\lambda}x}$ would be monotonic. Also, if $\lambda = 0$ , then the particular solutions would be $e^{0x} = 1$ and $x$ which are not periodic. So, given that the result of your differential equation is periodic, we are left with only one explanation: $\lambda < 0$